# Django queryset flipping

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

Is there any way to flip the relationship in a Django querset? **Such as turning a Foo queryset into a Bar queryset if all Foo objects have a foreign key to Bar?**

Take the following example:

```
#condition_n are previously defined statements that results in either True or False
if condition_1:
    foo_qs = Foo.objects.filter(bar__something=...)
    if condition_2:
        foo_qs = foo_qs.filter(bar__another_thing=...)
        if condition_3:
            #you get the point
```

now this will result in some queryset `foo_qs` depending on the evaluation of the `condition_n` type statements. If I wanted to also get the bar queryset that would result from that, I could do the following:

```
#condition_n are previously defined statements that results in either True or False
    if condition_1:
        foo_qs = Foo.objects.filter(bar__something=...)
        bar_qs = Bar.objects.filter(something=...)
        if condition_2:
            foo_qs = foo_qs.filter(bar__another_thing=...)
            bar_qs = Bar.objects.filter(another_thing=...)
            if condition_3:
                #you get the point
```

but ideally I would like to take any queryset, and give it the name of the foreign key ("bar" in this case), and have it flip to the equivalent queryset. **Is there any way about doing this?**

Comment: I don't have time for a proper answer but - using Q objects you can do `Q(**{'key': 'value'})`. Key is simply a string so it's easy to manipulate

Comment: please put some real code ... as well as what you expect back .... its not clear (at least not to me) what you are asking for (perhaps include a simplified bar/foo model class as well)

Comment: Why not construct the `bar_qs` queryset as above and then get the `foo_qs` queryset with `Foo.objects.filter(bar__in=bar_qs)`?

Comment: @KevinChristopherHenry Because the actual situation is significanly more complex where I can't actually just make the queryset for `qs_bar` easily

Answer (score 1):

> Such as turning a Foo queryset into a Bar queryset if all Foo objects have a foreign key to Bar?

Why not? Here's one approach, if you always write the base query as the one local to the object in question.

```
bar_query = {
   'something': 'something',
}

def prefix_fk(query, prefix):
    prefixed_query = {}
    for key, value in query.items():
        prefixed_query[prefix+key] = value
    return prefixed_query

Foo.objects.filter(**prefix_fk(bar_query, 'bar__'))
Bar.objects.filter(**bar_query)

if condition_2:
    bar_query['another_query'] = 'foobar'
    Foo.objects.filter(**prefix_fk(bar_query, 'bar__'))
    Bar.objects.filter(**bar_query)
```

Comment: @RyanSaxe is this not the answer you're looking for? (and if so, why?)